# Кнопка "назад" для возврата к предыдущему состоянию React?

Tags: reactjs, history, state

В состоянии хранится менюшка (объекты). При клике на пункт меню происходит перерисовка меню из состояния. Я хочу сделать кнопку "назад", чтобы можно было возвращаться к предыдущему состоянию.

```
state = {
"menu": [
        {
            "title": "Material", 
            "level": 0,
            "id": uuid.v4(),
            "parentItem":"Root",
            "childs": true,
            "show": true, 
        },      
        {
            "title": "Vlog", 
            "level": -2,
            "id": uuid.v4(),
            "parentItem":"Creativity",      
            "childs": false,
            "show": false,               
        },      
    ], 
"notes": [
            {
                "note": "Here you can write your notes!",
                "id": uuid.v4(),
                "categoryNote": "default"
            }
        ],
"techVars": 
            {
                "showNote": false, 
                "category": null
                }       
}
```

Мне подсказали, что я могу создать функцию вроде

```
goBack = () => this.setState(({menu})=> ({menu: menu.slice(0, -1),}))
```

Но это вроде не подходит, так как мне нужно всё состояние поменять, а в нём есть объекты без массивов.
Вопрос, как всё-таки извлекать предыдущие состояний из state? 
Чтобы можно было гулять как по истории в браузере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное вы неправильно поняли подсказку, которую Вам дали. Скорее всего имелось ввиду сохранять весь стейт в виде массива, в какое-то поле `state`, например `history`, и по нему уже гулять.

Что то вроде такого:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
  
    this.state = {
      history: [],
      userName: ""
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.history.length === this.state.history.length) {
      // чтобы удалить ссылки на объекты
      const stateTemp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prevState));
      delete stateTemp.history;
      this.setState({
        history: [...prevState.history, stateTemp]
      })
    }
  }

  returnToPrevState() {
    // чтобы удалить ссылки на объекты
    const history = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.history));
    const prevState = history.pop();
    this.setState({
      ...prevState,
      history
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={(e) => this.setState({userName: e.target.value})} value={this.state.userName} />
        <button onClick={() => this.returnToPrevState()}>Previous value</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

[Источник на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44514623/go-to-previous-state-in-reactjs)

P.S. Я считаю подобный функционал ужасом в разработке и никогда бы не применял такое в реальных проектах.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ!! А как бы вы делали на реальном проекте?

Comment: Контролировать состояния каждого элемента отдельно, можно вынести в отдельный сервис логику по работе с историей и переиспользовать его. Не стоит привязыватся к реактовскому стейту, потому что это во-первых неочевидно, во-вторых в дальнейшем приведет к тому что в истории будет копится большое количество не используемых данных, что будет влиять на производительность и поведение

Comment: Понимаю. А какие отдельные сервисы вы порекомендуете? Я видел вроде с использованием Redux это можно сделать.

Comment: Имелось ввиду самописный функционал вынести в отдельный файл, и переиспользовать